# Square root of a specific matrix over $\Bbb Z$

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-analysis, matrix-congruences

Let

$ B^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 
-2&0&0 \\
-1&-4&-1\\
2&4&0\\ \end{bmatrix}^2 = \begin{bmatrix}
4&0&0\\
4&12&4\\
-8&-16&-4\\ \end{bmatrix} = A similar to \begin{bmatrix}
4&0&0\\
0&0&-16\\
0&1&8\\ \end{bmatrix} = rcf(A)
$

Now, as far as i know there is a fact that if $A,B$ in $M(3,\Bbb Z)$ are similar, then, $A$ has square root in $M(3,\Bbb Z) \iff B$ has a square root in $M(3,\Bbb Z) $

Therefore, since $A$ has a square root over $\Bbb Z$, and $A \sim rfc(A)$ . rcf of $A$ must have a square root over $\Bbb Z$.

However , using other research on computing  square root of a matrix, I come up with

$\begin{bmatrix}
2&0&0\\
0&1&-4\\
0&1/4&3\\ \end{bmatrix}$

That is not in $M(3,\Bbb Z)$, maybe becuase it is just one of its square roots.

But, by the fact, I am certain that $rcf(A)$ has a square root over $\Bbb Z$.

I tried a desperate move letting $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i$ be integers, and

$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c\\
d&e&f\\
g&h&i\\ \end{bmatrix}^2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
4&0&0\\
0&0&-16\\
0&1&8\\ \end{bmatrix}$

Then I tried to evaluate $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i$ . But it does not work. I got stuck. Whatever I do.

Please help me with this huhuhu.

Answer (score 1):

One square root of $rcf(A)$ in $M_3(\mathbb{Z})$  is

$\begin{pmatrix}-2&1&4\\12&-2&-16\\-3&1&6\end{pmatrix}$.